# Powering a number as a divide and conquer solution

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, computer-science-theory

When we write powering a number as a divide and conquer algorithm in theoretical computer science the runtime would be `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Θ(1)` in my opinion, yet according to my teacher's slides it is `T(n) = T(n/2) + Θ(1)`. Why that? I added the 2 because the algorithm gets split into 2 subproblems? Am I wrong?
[image: Slide of the prof]

Comment: Why do you have a multiplier(2) in your answer? Can you explain?

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand it the number  (2 in my case) is the number of subproblems, as the problem of a^n = a^n/2 * a^n/2 thus 2 subproblems. While n/2 represents the size of the subproblems.

Comment: Isn't the answer for the two part is same? Then why do we need to call it twice?

Comment: I now added a picture of my prof's slide

Comment: So you mean if both parts are the same we don't have to call it twice? Would explain things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each step the problem is divided into two small identical parts. Since these are identical, there is no need to do the computation for each of those. Therefore there is no need to a multiplier `2`.